# How to expose Scalar Types with GraphQL ruby gem

Tags: ruby, graphql

I'm creating a project to implement GraphQL around an existing API, and I'm trying to add new Scalar types (`id` & `title` respectively) to provide structure around my query.

#### This is the query schema I'm aiming for:

```
query{
  allPlaylists {
    id 
    title
  }
}
```

I've read the gem's [documentation regarding Scalar Types](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/graphql/GraphQL/ScalarType), but it's very unclear where I should place new ScalarType definitions.

**Here is a snippet of my query, my full repo is also [saved on GitHub](https://github.com/DrianHillman/Spotless-API/blob/6b0afeea77d3a77d333b5bf9a95c0be09b436f79/app/graphql/types/query_type.rb):**

```
// query_type.rb

Types::QueryType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name "Query"
  # Add root-level fields here.
  # They will be entry points for queries on your schema.

  field :allPlaylists, types.String do
    description "Playlists that belong to the user"
    resolve ->(obj, args, ctx) {
      Playlist.all.map { |x| x }
    }
  end
end
```

> As you can see, I currently only have the `allPlaylists` **root-level** query defined.

Though the documentation is fairly unclear about this, I do plan to submit a PR to help clarify this once I strike a solution. Alternatively, if there are any working examples I can refer to it'd be very much welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Per some [clarification from the gem contributors](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues/670)— **defining an Object Type is the correct tool for this job, rather than a Scaler Type**.